# Where is PowerShell 2.0 ICmdletProviderSupportsHelp Implemented?

Tags: powershell-2.0

It seems the [System.Management.Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation(v=VS.85).aspx) assembly only ever exists in version 1.0.0.0 on my system, available in the GAC as well as in the following folder:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

I can confirm that I do have PowerShell 2.0 installed, though, since I have support for PowerShell modules and remoting working from the shell...

Looking through Reflector, I can observe that the [ICmdletProviderSupportsHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.provider.icmdletprovidersupportshelp(VS.85).aspx) interface is definitely not there.
So, the question is, where is it implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the reference assemblies for the additions in PSH V2 you need a recent (V7 or later) version of the Windows SDK.

But note that these still appear as V1.x, e.g. strong name `System.Management.Automation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`.

But the file version is 6.1.7600.16385, which is later than the reference assemblies from V1, and it does contain `ICmdletProviderSupportsHelp`.

(This lack of a version change seems, to me, to be down to wanting 100% forward compatibility from PSH V1: the V2 assemblies add things, but do not remove or change anything that existed for V1.)

Comment: This indeed does the trick.
The fact that version is still v1.0.0.0 is *very* confusing.